# How can I reuse an environment definition of a supervisor process for multiple processes

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

I have multiple supervisor programs defined and they all have the same environment variables defined, now I needed to add a new one and I had to add it to each program section. Is there a way to define a environment variable which is valid for the whole supervisor config file and which I could reuse? E.g file under `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/foo.conf`:

```
my_env=foo=2,bar="hi",zee="ok"

[program:foo]
environment=my_env

[program:bar]
environment=my_env
```